# SyncObjects.Item Method (Outlook), explain

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook, vba, sync

This link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/syncobjects-item-method-outlook
is devoid of explanations. What is the meaning of SyncObjects.Item(1), for example? Can I have a practical example?
SyncObjects.Item(1) corresponds at the first folder in the my folder (email address) or the first folder in absolute on outlook?

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Do you understand the concepts of an Array?

Comment: I know what the arrays are but I do not know Item(1) to which folder point.

Comment: What? Item(1) would point to the first SyncObject in the Array.  Your response doesn’t seem to indicate you understand Arrays.

Comment: What do you want an example of?  Don’t answer a “code example” that would be out of scope.  Trying to help you.

Comment: But i dont know if items started from the first folder in the my account address folder or of the first account of outlook (sorry for bad english, i am italian).

Comment: the question is Item(1) corresponds at the first folder in the my folder (email address) or the first folder in absolute on outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are discovering *collection classes*. One such class is the `VBA.Collection` class; in Excel, you've probably encountered the `Workbooks` collection class, or the `Worksheets` collection, or `UserForms`, or `Controls`; `SyncObjects` is just another such collection.

All collection classes have something in common. They're classes, which means they represent objects - but they also *contain items*. Some collections contain only one type of objects (e.g. `Worksheets` only contains `Worksheet` objects), others contain *any* type of objects.

By convention, all collections are 1-based, so the first item in the collection will be at index 1.

All collections can be *enumerated* - that is, iterated using a `For Each...Next` loop. They can do this because they all expose a hidden `[_NewEnum]` member that has special hidden attributes.

```
For Each foo In myCollection
    Debug.Print foo.Bar
Next
```

All collections can also be *indexed* - that is, their individual items can be accessed by index, or by some kind of key/name. This allows iterating a collection using a `For...Next` loop - and this is where the `Item` property kicks in:

```
For i = 1 To myCollection.Count
    Debug.Print myCollection.Item(i).Bar
Next
```

The `Item` property, by convention, is also the collection class' *default member* (some collection classes can have different default members, e.g. `ADODB.Recordset.Fields`) - it has a special hidden attribute that makes it possible to *implicitly* invoke that member, so you can omit it:

```
For i = 1 To myCollection.Count
    Debug.Print myCollection(i).Bar
Next
```

...and the outcome is exactly the same as if `Item` was explicitly spelled out.

> **Note** collections *want* to be iterated with a `For Each...Next` loop. Accessing collection items by index is always going to be slower than leveraging the hidden `[_NewEnum]` member. And [the difference is remarkable](http://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/).

For collection classes, implicitly invoking this *default member* is convenient - however other (non-collection) classes can also have default members, and implicitly invoking them is a common source of bugs, because the code isn't *doing what it says*, and/or *saying what it does*.

---

> *What am I saying with Item(1), Item(2), Item(3), etc.?*

What `.Item(1)` is saying, is "give me the first item in the collection". In the case of `SyncObjects`, each item is a `SyncObject` object, so you'd retrieve that item with the `Set` keyword:

```
Set firstItem = syncList.Item(1)
```

---

> *SyncObjects.Item(1) corresponds at the first folder in the my folder (email address) or the first folder in absolute on outlook?*

That should be irrelevant: the entire point of a collection is to encapsulate a group of objects and allow them to be iterated. Which specific object is first, second, third, or last, isn't guaranteed by the implementation: you would use the properties of the individual items (e.g. `Name`) to find out what specific `SyncObject` you're looking at, not its index in a collection.

```
Dim current As SyncObject
For Each current In Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI").SyncObjects
    Debug.Print current.Name
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a reply, I tested with

dim try as string

try = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").SyncObjects.Item(1)
in the debug mode
try is equal at: "Tutti gli account"

try = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").SyncObjects.Item(2)

is equal at: "Cartelle applicazioni"

[image]

Comment: And you can't assume that will be the case every time your code runs, as I explained in my answer. Assuming that index 1 or 2 corresponds to a specific instance of a specific object at run-time will definitely come back to bite you, at one point or another.